# method is undefined issue

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i worked on a sqlite tutorial and i thought it was clear but i have a problem. I want to create and read a db but there is an error in my code. I just started with android and java so i need some help with this.

i have used wedstrijdgeschiedenis:

```
package com.justus.referee;

public class WedstrijdenGeschiedenis {

private int id;
private String thuisclub;
private String bezoekers;

public WedstrijdenGeschiedenis(){}

public WedstrijdenGeschiedenis(String thuisclub, String bezoekers) {
    super();
    this.thuisclub = thuisclub;
    this.bezoekers = bezoekers;
}

//getters & setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Wedstrijd [id=" + id + ", thuis=" + thuisclub + ", Bezoekers=" + bezoekers
            + "]";
}

}
```

and i use MySqLiteHelper:

```
package com.justus.referee;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.justus.referee.WedstrijdenGeschiedenis;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WedstrijdenDB";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create wedstrijdenGeschiedenis table
        String CREATE_WEDSTRIJD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE wedstrijden ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "thuisclub TEXT, "+
                "bezoekers TEXT )";

        // create wedstrijdenGeschiedeniss table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_WEDSTRIJD_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older wedstrijdenGeschiedeniss table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wedstrijden");

        // create fresh wedstrijdenGeschiedeniss table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) 
     */

    // WedstrijdenGeschiedeniss table name
    private static final String TABLE_WEDSTRIJD = "wedstrijden";

    // WedstrijdenGeschiedeniss Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_THUIS = "thuisclub";
    private static final String KEY_BEZOEKER = "bezoekers";

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_THUIS,KEY_BEZOEKER};

    public void addWedstrijd(WedstrijdenGeschiedenis wedstrijd){
        Log.d("addWedstrijd", wedstrijd.toString());
        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_THUIS, wedstrijd.getThuis()); // get thuis 
        values.put(KEY_BEZOEKER, wedstrijd.getBezoeker()); // get bezoeker

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_WEDSTRIJD, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        // 4. close
        db.close(); 
    }
```

but in my eclipse there are three errors in this part of the code:

```
// 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_THUIS, wedstrijd.getThuis()); // get thuis 
                values.put(KEY_BEZOEKER, wedstrijd.getBezoeker()); // get bezoeker
```

the error is "***the method getThuis() is undefined for the type WedstrijdenGeschiedenis***"

And i can't find the reason of this error. Sorry for the newbie problem!

Comment: Can you include the method getThuis()?

Comment: That was the problem! Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following methods to WedstrijdenGeschiedenis class:

```
public String getThuis(){
    return thuisclub;
}

public String getBezoekers(){
    return bezoekers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see getThuis() method in the WedstrijdenGeschiedenis class.
Obviously you forget create getters for variables "thuisclub" and "bezoekers".

Answer (score 0):

I forget to create the getters indeed. Stupid rookie mistake (and it was not mentioned in the tutorial).

I added this:

```
public int getId() {
        return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
}
public String getThuis() {
        return thuisclub;
}
public void setThuis(String thuisclub) {
        this.thuisclub = thuisclub;
}
public String getBezoeker() {
        return bezoekers;
}
public void setBezoeker(String bezoekers) {
        this.bezoekers = bezoekers;
}
```

and this made the code working. Thanks!